# Global non-namespaced @helper in Razor views .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Using MVC 4: Is it in any way possible to achieve the following, without having the `@helper`-part inline in every view that uses it:

```
@helper _(string msg) {
    @msg
}
<p>@_("Hello")</p>
```

...So that the layout file has it or it's placed somewhere else that's shared? I.e. only this in a given view: `@_("Hello")`.

I've tried:

- adding it to `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` (Doesn't work)
- adding it to `App_Code` (Works but is namespaced)
- searching Google for a couple of hours for hints

I'm aware that I could just use a namespace but I'd *really* like to avoid that for readability and shorter code.

I'm still relatively new to .NET in general so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does "namespacing" affect readability? It just a single `using` statement in the beginning of your file.

Comment: If you want to use a helper method in all views, add the namespace to the web.config in each views folder you have (non-areas/areas).

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: I might've explained myself wrong; I'd like to avoid: `@Utils._("Hello")`

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved without creating a helper.  Use a extension method.

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
  public static class WebViewPageExtensions
  {
    public static IHtmlString _(this WebViewPage page, string msg)
    {
      return new HtmlString(msg);
    }
  }
}
```

Then in all your views:

```
<p>@_("Hello")</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I'm looking for! However, I can't get it to work... I've added your example to the root of my MVC project with adjusted namespace as the only change. I've also added that same namespace in Views/Web.config.